# EXC_BAD_ACCESS for NSXMLParser code

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing, exc-bad-access, nsxmlparser

I have written the below code to parse `RSS feeds.` but i keep getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in foundCharacter method when it tries to compare element with `@"title"`.Any idea where am i going wrong?

```
NSMutableDictionary * item;
NSMutableString * title;
NSMutableString * link;
NSString *element;
NSMutableArray *feeds; 

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    element = elementName;
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        title = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
        link = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];
        [feeds addObject:[item copy]];
        NSLog(@"feeds :: %@",feeds);
    }


}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [title appendString:string];`enter code here`
    }else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]){
        [link appendString:string];
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry , its still crashing at the same line of code

Comment: You need to debug and check the element's value at that point. It could be nil.

Comment: The 'element' variable not being used in the method -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string, it should be string.

Comment: i am not using ARC.. and its crashing as i reach the line of code

Comment: @user2071152 I have declared element variable to be NSString

Comment: Well this error happens when you are trying to access a variable which has been deallocated. You have to retain and release your variable manually.

Comment: As Justafinger pointed could you please allocate memory for element variable and check.

Comment: I get (NSString *) element = 0x0bf729b0 as description on the variable element. i haven't retained or released my variable at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the mistake is in this line:

```
element = elementName;
```

You have to init the variable element. So write this one:

```
element = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:elementName];
```

Then it should work.

Comment: thank you so  much, this really did work. I accept your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept it with the green check on the left side of the answer.
And always remember to initialize your instances :)

Comment: Benjamin, I gave you some upvotes in lieu of an accepted answer.  But you should also suggest `element = [elementName copy]`

Comment: Thanks Steve. Yes, your solution is maybe even better than mine :)